# Python Loan table integer error

Tags: python-3.x

```
Ok I'm having alot of trouble with this code because I can't get the table to work properly. I'm getting an error code that reads :
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\project1.py", line 71, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\project1.py", line 70, in main
    print(pmtOptions(APR,periods_year, term,loan_amount))
  File "C:\Users\User\Documents\python\project1.py", line 46, in pmtOptions
    EMI = (loan_amount*pow((intRate/12)+1, (terms[x]))*intRate/12)/(pow(intRate/12+1, (terms[x])) - 1)
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

My full code is below. The main function seems to be running ok until I get to the point where I have to call the third function. I was able to adjust some of the string formatting but I can't seem to figure out to get the values to work properly so they print. I've tried changing the main function as well, but then have to modify the variables inside the pmtOptions function again along with them. I was able to fix a similar problem by joining one of my lists to print it but I dont understand how I'm supposed to do this with an equation or if there is something else I am doing wrong. I'm a beginner in coding so I can't tell what the issue is..

```
#payment options
def pmtOptions(APR,periods_year, term,loan_amount):

#first save rows and columbs as a list to access them again [interest rates]
    interestRates =[]
    apr = APR-1.5
#while loop for interest rates APR can be any APR have to iterate over halves 
    while apr <= (APR+1.5):
        interestRates.append(apr)
        apr = apr  + .5
#list for term values
        periods_year = int(periods_year)
        term = int(term)
        term_list =[]
        terms = (periods_year*term)
#while loop have to iterate for 6 in rows
    while terms <= (periods_year*term):
        term_list.append(terms)
        terms = terms + 6
#headers for table
    print("\n %35s %20s "%(" ", "Alternative Loan Payment Table"))
    print("%35s %20s "%(" ", "=============================="))
    print("%42s %20s "%(" ", "Interest Rates"))
    print("\n %10s "%(" "), end="")
#interest rate headigs with for loop

    for apr in interestRates:
        print(" %8.2f%% "%(apr), end = "")
#other heading
    print("\n %8s "%("# Payments"), end = "") #note to self to start new line had to take print out of for loop
#more headings
    for apr in interestRates:
         print("%8s "%("========"), end = "")
#term values remember new line
    for x in range(0,len(term_list)):
        print("\n %8s ".join(str(x) for x in term_list))

#intrest rate value
    for y in range(0,len(interestRates)):
        intRate = interestRates[x]/100.0
#filling in EMI equation for values
    EMI = (loan_amount*pow((intRate/12)+1, (terms[x]))*intRate/12)/(pow(intRate/12+1, (terms[x])) - 1)
#printing out values lets hope this works
    print(" $%7.2f "%(EMI),end = "") #remember do not include % in parens

#creating the main function part 1
def main():
    print("This program is used to analyze commercial real estate loans.")

#function variables
    purchase_price = input("Please input original purchase price: ")
    down_payment = input("Please input total down payment: ")
    APR = float(input("Please input APR: "))
    periods_year = input("Please input the number of payments per year: ")
    #periods_year = int(periods_year)
    term = input("Please input loan length in years: ")
    #term = int(term)
    first_payment = input("Please input date of first payment in form MM/DD/YYYY: ")
    loan_amount = float(purchase_price) - float(down_payment)
#seperating str
    dates = first_payment.split('/')
    day = int(dates[0])
    month = int(dates[1])
    year = int(dates[2])
#calling payment function
    print(pmtOptions(APR,periods_year, term,loan_amount))
main()


#loancalc function
def loanCalc(APR, period_year, loan_amount, total_payments):
#interest charged per period
    r = APR/(period_year)
#amount paid in each period
    P = (r * loan_amount)/(1- (1+r) ** (-(total_payments)))
#amount paid over life of loan
    final_value = (P * total_payments)
#part 1 calculations with main variables
    total_payments = float(term) * float(down_payment)

#total_amount = loanCalc(APR, periods_year, loan_amount, total_payments)
    end_date = str(day) + "/" + str(month) + "/" + str(year + int(term))
    total_interest = r*total_payments
#remember to return not print
    return final_value
```

Comment: When I run the code posted I get a different error.

Comment: what error are you getting? I can re paste the code that I have open.

Comment: I edited the post to repaste the code.

Comment: I also ran it again, and pasted the error code.

Comment: In the line referred to in the diagnostic message only the variable `terms` is subscripted. This means that `terms` must be an `int` and you're trying to treat it as a list.

Comment: how can i switch it to an integer in this case?

Comment: That's not what I meant. You used `terms[x]` so Python expects `terms` to be a list but it isn't; so the statement fails. I notice that you also have a variable `terms_list`. Have you confused `terms` for `terms_list`?

Comment: ahh, i see what you're saying. let me try that and see if it works. I think I did switch them.

Comment: thanks. That was able to fix it, now i just can't get the EMI values to iterate over the interest rates. The table won't fill out. I was having the same problem with the payments but fixed it. Is there something that I need to add to the EMI section to get it fill out the table?

Comment: You should enter a fresh question for this, with the most up-to-date code.